# Undefined index: checkbox_fields error when submitting safecracker form

Tags: safecracker, forms

Here is my form

```
{exp:safecracker
    channel="dummy"
    class="form-horizontal"
    dynamic_title="Place"
    error_handling="inline"
    include_jquery="no"
    return="test/place-form-done"
    safecracker_head="no"
}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Place</legend>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="place" value="" id="place" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
{/exp:safecracker}
```

When I submit, I get this

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: checkbox_fields
Filename: libraries/safecracker_lib.php
Line Number: 1210
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in ExpressionEngine 2.5.3, see [BugTracker](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18237). You need to be logged in to view.

The fix requires adjusting some code in the SafeCracker modules file. See below…

```
Open system/expressionengine/modules/safecracker/libraries/api/Api_sc_channel_entries.php and find this code on line 66:

$checkbox_fields = explode('|', $data['checkbox_fields']); 
And REPLACE it with:

$checkbox_fields = isset($data['checkbox_fields']) ? explode('|', $data['checkbox_fields']) : array();
```

This may have been patched in the EE 2.5.5 update, but I'm not certain. You can apply this fix manually.

I should also mention that for some people applying the fix [caused another error](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18233) to occur, see…

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: checkbox_fields
Filename: libraries/safecracker_lib.php
Line Number: 1210

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 402
```

This was logged as a separate bug, with it's own fix. But if that error occurs for you, the fix is listed below.

```
Find this code starting at line 1210 in /system/expressionengine/modules/safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php:

foreach (explode('|', $_POST['checkbox_fields']) as $checkbox)
{
    if ( ! isset($_POST[$checkbox]))
    {
        $_POST[$checkbox] = '';
    }
} 
Replace that block of code with this:

if (isset($_POST['checkbox_fields']))
{
    foreach (explode('|', $_POST['checkbox_fields']) as $checkbox)
    {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$checkbox]))
        {
            $_POST[$checkbox] = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

This was patched in 2.5.4, [according to the changelog](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-4).

Comment: I was going to mention upgrading, but didn't want to qualify the answer against what 3rd party add-ons he might be using that require postponing the upgrade.